# How to build an angular 2 library using webpack and publish it to npm?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

> I want to build an angular 2 library using webpack and publish it to
>   npm. I have the code for the library and now I want to build it for
>   npm my webpack common looks like this.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const ngcWebpack = require('ngc-webpack');

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const AOT = helpers.hasNpmFlag('aot');
const METADATA = {
    title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2290 from @AngularClass',
    baseUrl: '/',
    isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
    isProd = options.env === 'production';
    return {

        /*
         * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
         * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
         * You can pass false to disable it.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
         */
        //cache: false,

        /*
         * The entry point for the bundle
         * Our Angular.js app
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
         */
        entry: {

            'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
            'ng2-tools': AOT ? './src/main.browser.aot.ts' :
                './src/index.ts'

        },

        /*
         * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
         */
        resolve: {

            /*
             * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
             */
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

            // An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
            modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

        },

        /*
         * Options affecting the normal modules.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
         */
        module: {

            rules: [

                /*
                 * Typescript loader support for .ts
                 *
                 * Component Template/Style integration using `angular2-template-loader`
                 * Angular 2 lazy loading (async routes) via `ng-router-loader`
                 *
                 * `ng-router-loader` expects vanilla JavaScript code, not TypeScript code. This is why the
                 * order of the loader matter.
                 *
                 * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
                 * See: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader
                 * See: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ng-router-loader
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
                            options: {
                                pretty: !isProd,
                                prod: isProd
                            }
                        },
                        { // MAKE SURE TO CHAIN VANILLA JS CODE, I.E. TS COMPILATION OUTPUT.
                            loader: 'ng-router-loader',
                            options: {
                                loader: 'async-import',
                                genDir: 'compiled',
                                aot: AOT
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                            options: {
                                configFileName: 'tsconfig.webpack.json'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
                        }
                    ],
                    exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
                },

                /*
                 * Json loader support for *.json files.
                 *
                 * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    use: 'json-loader'
                },

                /*
                 * to string and css loader support for *.css files (from Angular components)
                 * Returns file content as string
                 *
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },

                /*
                 * to string and sass loader support for *.scss files (from Angular components)
                 * Returns compiled css content as string
                 *
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },

                /* Raw loader support for *.html
                 * Returns file content as string
                 *
                 * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: 'raw-loader',
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
                },

                /*
                 * File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
                    use: 'file-loader'
                },

                /* File loader for supporting fonts, for example, in CSS files.
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                    use: 'file-loader'
                }

            ],

        },

        /*
         * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
         */
        plugins: [
            new AssetsPlugin({
                path: helpers.root('lib'),
                filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
                prettyPrint: true
            }),

            /*
             * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
             * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
             *
             * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
             */
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            /*
             * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
             * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
             * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
             *
             * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
             * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
             */
            new CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'polyfills',
                chunks: ['polyfills']
            }),
            // This enables tree shaking of the vendor modules
            new CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: ['main'],
                minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource)
            }),
            new CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
            }),
            /**
             * Plugin: ContextReplacementPlugin
             * Description: Provides context to Angular's use of System.import
             *
             * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#contextreplacementplugin
             * See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
             */
            new ContextReplacementPlugin(
                // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
                /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)src(\\|\/)linker/,
                helpers.root('src'), // location of your src
                {
                    // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
                }
            ),
            /**
             * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
             *
             * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
             */
            new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),

            // Fix Angular 2
            new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
                /facade(\\|\/)async/,
                helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.js')
            ),
            new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
                /facade(\\|\/)collection/,
                helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.js')
            ),
            new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
                /facade(\\|\/)errors/,
                helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js')
            ),
            new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
                /facade(\\|\/)lang/,
                helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js')
            ),
            new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
                /facade(\\|\/)math/,
                helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/math.js')
            ),

            new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin({
                disabled: !AOT,
                tsConfig: helpers.root('tsconfig.webpack.json'),
                resourceOverride: helpers.root('config/resource-override.js')
            })
        ],
        // Specify the correct order the scripts will be injected in

        /*
         * Include polyfills.ts or mocks for various node stuff
         * Description: Node configuration
         *
         * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
         */
        node: {
            global: true,
            crypto: 'empty',
            process: true,
            module: false,
            clearImmediate: false,
            setImmediate: false
        }

    };
}
```

> And this is my webpack dev

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
const webpackMergeDll = webpackMerge.strategy({plugins: 'replace'});
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js'); // the settings that are common to prod and dev

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const AddAssetHtmlPlugin = require('add-asset-html-webpack-plugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const NamedModulesPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');

/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}).metadata, {
    host: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    ENV: ENV,
    HMR: HMR
});


const DllBundlesPlugin = require('webpack-dll-bundles-plugin').DllBundlesPlugin;

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
    return webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {

        /**
         * Developer tool to enhance debugging
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/build-performance#sourcemaps
         */
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

        /**
         * Options affecting the output of the compilation.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
         */
        output: {

            /**
             * The output directory as absolute path (required).
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path
             */
            path: helpers.root('lib'),

            /**
             * Specifies the name of each output file on disk.
             * IMPORTANT: You must not specify an absolute path here!
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename
             */
            filename: '[name].js',

            /**
             * The filename of the SourceMaps for the JavaScript files.
             * They are inside the output.path directory.
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-sourcemapfilename
             */
            sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',

            /** The filename of non-entry chunks as relative path
             * inside the output.path directory.
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-chunkfilename
             */
            chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',

            library: 'ac_[name]',
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            umdNamedDefine: true
        },

        module: {

            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'tslint-loader',
                            options: {
                                configFile: 'tslint.json'
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
                },

              /*
               * css loader support for *.css files (styles directory only)
               * Loads external css styles into the DOM, supports HMR
               *
               */
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                    include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },

              /*
               * sass loader support for *.scss files (styles directory only)
               * Loads external sass styles into the DOM, supports HMR
               *
               */
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                    include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },

            ]

        },

        plugins: [

            /**
             * Plugin: DefinePlugin
             * Description: Define free variables.
             * Useful for having development builds with debug logging or adding global constants.
             *
             * Environment helpers
             *
             * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
             */
            // NOTE: when adding more properties, make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
            new DefinePlugin({
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
                'process.env': {
                    'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                    'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
                }
            }),

            new DllBundlesPlugin({
                bundles: {
                    polyfills: [
                        'core-js',
                        {
                            name: 'zone.js',
                            path: 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'zone.js',
                            path: 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js'
                        },
                    ],
                    vendor: [
                        '@angular/platform-browser',
                        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
                        '@angular/core',
                        '@angular/common',
                        '@angular/forms',
                        '@angular/http',
                        '@angular/router',
                        '@angularclass/hmr',
                        'rxjs',
                    ]
                },
                dllDir: helpers.root('dll'),
                webpackConfig: webpackMergeDll(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
                    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
                    plugins: []
                })
            }),

            /**
             * Plugin: AddAssetHtmlPlugin
             * Description: Adds the given JS or CSS file to the files
             * Webpack knows about, and put it into the list of assets
             * html-webpack-plugin injects into the generated html.
             *
             * See: https://github.com/SimenB/add-asset-html-webpack-plugin
             */
            new AddAssetHtmlPlugin([
                { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('polyfills')}`) },
                { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('vendor')}`) }
            ]),

            /**
             * Plugin: NamedModulesPlugin (experimental)
             * Description: Uses file names as module name.
             *
             * See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/a04ffb928365b19feb75087c63f13cadfc08e1eb
             */
            // new NamedModulesPlugin(),

            /**
             * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
             *
             * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
             */
            new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                debug: true,
                options: {

                }
            }),

        ],

        /**
         * Webpack Development Server configuration
         * Description: The webpack-dev-server is a little node.js Express server.
         * The server emits information about the compilation state to the client,
         * which reacts to those events.
         *
         * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
         */
        devServer: {
            port: METADATA.port,
            host: METADATA.host,
            historyApiFallback: true,
            watchOptions: {
                aggregateTimeout: 300,
                poll: 1000
            }
        },

      /*
       * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
       * Description: Node configuration
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
       */
        node: {
            global: true,
            crypto: 'empty',
            process: true,
            module: false,
            clearImmediate: false,
            setImmediate: false
        }

    });
}
```

> What I want is the webpack to not bundle the library and use it just
>   to compile all components in the lib folder keeping the save folder
>   structure, so I can publish it and reference in another project. Can I achieve 
>   this result with webpack ? Or should I look at other build tool ?
>   Also a guide about how to build a library for angular 2 with webpack
>   would be helpful :)

what I want to achieve is build all files with webpack and emit .js, .d.ts compiled fieldes which embed the style and the html (with angular2-template-loader and awesome-typescript-loader) to a lib folder